# Achieve this navigation menu layout

Tags: html, css, width, children

[image]

I need to achieve this layout, please note on the current item,

The 3 sublists are supoused to be children of the current item,

The problem here is that if I set the position absolute and left:0 and width:100%; the max width would be determined for the parent's width,

So,

How can I keep the lists children and make them use the whole avaliable space?

this is my markup for now: (can i keep it?)

```
<nav>
    <ul class="main">
        <li><a href="<?=base_url('grupo-cabau')?>"><?=lang('grupo-cabau')?></a></li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="<?=base_url('nuestros-hoteles')?>"><?=lang('nuestros-hoteles')?></a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>list
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="<?=base_url('aquasol')?>">item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?=base_url('bahia')?>">item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li>listt                               <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li>list
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?=base_url('trabaja-con-nosotros')?>"><item</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=base_url('contacto')?>">item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="lang">
        <li>ESP
            <ul>
                <li>ENG</li>
                <li>DEU</li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My current implementation (almost there):

[image]

```
header .wrapper > div nav ul.main > li.active > ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 141px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Problem when I set li.active to position:relative (very far from there):

[image]

So question is,

How can the position:absolute child be bigger (and left,right properties respond to the layout) with the parent being position:relative???

Is my only chance to take the list out of the tree?

Comment: can you post your relevant CSS (*so far*) and perhaps a live jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can you make it more clear ?

Comment: Hey, I add a quick jsfidle that you can work on: http://jsfiddle.net/DLhpB/2/

Comment: Does the menu have a fixed width? The problem is that you want to set the width depending on the width of the parents parent... That may be getting difficult.

Comment: I am on it; but i am working with sass and it's being a pain in the ass so far..

Comment: @LinkinTED yes, fixed width

Comment: You want to position the sub-menus left: 0 independent of the parent menu??

Comment: I think so, i would need, in this case;left to make reference to the grand-parent instead of the parent... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is set the width based on a parent's parent. That is the problem. But as you commented, the menu has a fixed width, which makes it easier.

I cleaned the HTML up to this:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2
        <ul>
            <li>List 2.1
                <ul>
                    <li>item 2.1.1</li>
                    <li>item 2.1.2</li>
                    <li>item 2.1.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>List 2.2
                <ul>
                    <li>item 2.2.1</li>
                    <li>item 2.2.2</li>
                    <li>item 2.2.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>list 2.3
                <ul>
                    <li>item 2.3.1</li>
                    <li>item 2.3.2</li>
                    <li>item 2.3.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Then made this CSS:

```
body, ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px; /* needs to be a fixed width */
    background: lightblue;
}
.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-right: -4px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.nav > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 500px; /* same width as .nav */
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
.nav > li > ul > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/4a98c/

You'll probably want to show the submenu on a :hover effect, check http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/4a98c/2/

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot! but i ned the li position:relative... any chance? http://jsfiddle.net/4a98c/4/

Comment: The problem here i have, also, is that each list item must have it's own list... [..]

Comment: Why do you need `position: relative`? Giving al the items an own list ain't a problem, check: http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/4a98c/5/

Comment: I see, that does give problems indeed. You could fix that by making an image and set that to the background of the active item.

Comment: I achieved it by setting same width and text algin center :) thanks for your light!